# how to prevent array from occupying slots in solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays, bytes32, uint256, get-storage-at

I have this simple contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract Ejemplo {

    //[123,456,789] input 
    function test(uint256[] calldata nums ) external {

    }
}
```

These are the storage locations of the objects

```
Location 0 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
Location 1 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
Location 2 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b
Location 3 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c8
Location 4 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000315
```

slot0 and slot1 are slots that apparently are typical of the array and that occupy 64bytes (2x32 bytes). Is there any way to prevent the array from occupying 2 slots?